# Singleton instantiation

Tags: java, singleton

Below show is the creation on the singleton object.

```
public class Map_en_US extends mapTree {

    private static Map_en_US m_instance;

    private Map_en_US() {}

    static{
        m_instance = new Map_en_US();
        m_instance.init();
    }

    public static Map_en_US getInstance(){
        return m_instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        //some code;
    }
}
```

My question is what is the reason for using a static block for instantiating. i am familiar with below form of instantiation of the singleton.

```
public static Map_en_US getInstance(){
    if(m_instance==null)
      m_instance = new Map_en_US();
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason is **thread safety**.

The form you said you are familiar with has the potential of initializing the singleton a large number of times. Moreover, even after it has been initialized multiple times, future calls to `getInstance()` by different threads might return different instances! Also, one thread might see a partially-initialized singleton instance! (let's say the constructor connects to a DB and authenticates; one thread might be able to get a reference to the singleton before the authentication happens, even if it is done in the constructor!)

There are some difficulties when dealing with threads:

1. ***Concurrency***: they have to potential to execute concurrently;
2. ***Visibility***: modifications to the memory made by one thread might not be visible to other threads;
3. ***Reordering***: the order in which the code is executed cannot be predicted, which can lead to very strange results.

You should study about these difficulties to understand precisely why those odd behaviors are perfectly legal in the JVM, why they are actually *good*, and how to protect from them.

The static block is guaranteed, by the JVM, to be executed only once (unless you load and initialize the class using different `ClassLoader`s, but the details are beyond the scope of this question, I'd say), and by one thread only, and the results of it are guaranteed to be visible to every other thread.

That's why you should initialize the singleton on the static block.

### My preferred pattern: thread-safe and lazy

The pattern above will instantiate the singleton on the first time the execution sees a reference to the class `Map_en_US` (actually, only a reference to the class itself will load it, but might not yet initialize it; for more details, check the reference). Maybe you don't want that. Maybe you want the singleton to be initialized only on the first call to `Map_en_US.getInstance()` (just as the pattern you said you are familiar with supposedly does).

If that's what you want, you can use the following pattern:

```
public class Singleton {
  private Singleton() { ... }
  private static class SingletonHolder {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
  }
  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.instance;
  }
}
```

In the code above, the singleton will only be instantiated when the class `SingletonHolder` is initialized. This will happen only once (unless, as I said before, you are using multiple ClassLoaders), the code will be executed by only one thread, the results will have no visibility problems, and the initialization will occur only on the first reference to `SingletonHolder`, which happens inside the `getInstance()` method. This is the pattern I use most often when I need a singleton.

### Another patterns...

#### 1. `synchronized getInstace()`

As discussed in the comments to this answer, there's another way to implement the singleton in a thread safe manner, and which is almost the same as the (broken) one you are familiar with:

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton instance;
  public static synchronized getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
      instance = new Singleton();
  }
}
```

The code above is guaranteed, by the memory model, to be thread safe. The JVM specification states the following (in a more cryptic way): let L be the lock of any object, let T1 and T2 be two threads. The release of L by T1 *happens-before* the acquisition of L by T2.

This means that every thing that has been done by T1 before releasing the lock will be visible to every other thread after they acquire the same lock.

So, suppose T1 is the first thread that entered the `getInstance()` method. Until it has finished, no other thread will be able to enter the same method (since it is synchronized). It will see that `instance` is null, will instantiate a `Singleton` and store it in the field. It will then release the lock and return the instance.

Then, T2, which was waiting for the lock, will be able to acquire it and enter the method. Since it acquired the same lock that T1 just released, T2 will see that the field `instance` contains *the exact same instance* of Singleton created by T1, and will simply return it. What is more, the initialization of the singleton, which has been done by T1, happened before the release of the lock by T1, which happened before the acquisition of the lock by T2, therefore there's no way T2 can see a partially-initialized singleton.

The code above is perfectly correct. The only problem is that the access to the singleton will be serialized. If it happens *a lot*, it will reduce the scalability of your application. That's why I prefer the `SingletonHolder` pattern I showed above: access to the singleton will be truly concurrent, without the need for synchronization!

#### 2. Double checked locking (DCL)

Often, people are scared about the cost of lock acquisition. I've read that nowadays it is not that relevant for most applications. The real problem with lock acquisition is that it hurts scalability by serializing access to the synchronized block.

Someone devised an ingenuous way to avoid acquiring a lock, and it has been called ***double-checked locking***. The problem is that ***most implementations are broken***. That is, most implementations are not thread-safe (ie, are as thread-unsafe as the `getInstace()` method on the original question).

The correct way to implement the DCL is as follows:

```
public class Singleton {
  private static volatile Singleton instance;
  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      synchronized {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = new Singleton();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

The difference between this correct and an incorrect implementation is the `volatile` keyword.

To understand why, let T1 and T2 be two threads. Let's first assume that the field is not volatile.

T1 enters the `getInstace()` method. It's the first one to ever enter it, so the field is null. It then enters the synchronized block, then the second if. It also evaluates to true, so T1 creates a new instance of the singleton and stores it in the field. The lock is then release, and the singleton is returned. For this thread, it is guaranteed that the Singleton is completely initialized.

Now, T2 enters the `getInstace()` method. It is possible (although not guaranteed) that it will see that `instance != null`. It will then skip the `if` block (and so it will never acquire the lock), and will directly return the instance of the Singleton. Due to *reordering*, it is possible that T2 will not see all the initialization performed by the Singleton in its constructor! Revisiting the db connection singleton example, T2 might see a connected but not yet authenticated singleton!

### For more information...

... I'd recommend a brilliant book, *Java Concurrency in Practice*, and also, the *Java Language Specification*.

Comment: _"...by different threads might return different instances!"_  ---- How's that?

Comment: the reason for _static block_ is not thread safety. The way it coded now, `Map_en_US` is unsafe (m_instance isn't `final`)

Comment: @Gruber Assume one thread returns an instance while the other is creating a new one (due to a racing condition). The second thread would overwrite the `instance` variable and return the newly created instance.

Comment: @Thomas .. Thx, got it! ... Hm, wouldn't _synchronized_ make the `getInstance` method threadsafe?!

Comment: @Thomas Not just that, different threads could continue to see different instances for an indefinite period of time. In the Java Memory Model, there are no guarantees about this.

Comment: @Neil actually, if `getInstance()` is declared `synchronized`, the memory model will guarantee the thread-safety of the singleton: there will be no concurrent initialization and, if L is a lock of any object, and T1 and T2 are two thread, the acquisition of L by T2 *happens-before* the release of L by T1, so T2 would see the field holding the singleton filled, and the constructor of the Singleton would have completed its execution for both threads. I will comment about that in my answer.

Comment: @gnat: in this context, `final` is not relevant. If a static field is initialized on the class initialization, it will be visible to all threads. The final would only disallow further modifications to the field. What you might be thinking is about final instance fields, which are guaranteed to be seen correctly initialized after the constructor returned, even on a not properly published instance.

Comment: Note that making the `getInstance()` method synchronized introduces some overhead for synchronization. This can be heavily reduced by `double checked locking` - have a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: @Thomas: ***be careful*** with double checked locking... most of the implementations you will find on the internet **are broken**. To be done properly, remember that the field must be marked `volatile`; if it is not volatile, it is necessarily broken.

Comment: @Bruno per my reading of JLS [17.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5) and [8.3.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2.1) there are no safety guarantees for _Map_en_US_. Another -1 is that the way I see it, thread un/safety is not an answer to question which was stated as _"what is the reason for using a static block"_

Comment: **update** there are safety guarantees: discussed with Bruno in comments to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121213/singleton-instantiation/7121406#7121406)

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize in the `getInstance()` method, you can get a racing conditions, i.e. if 2 threads execute the `if(m_instance == null)` check simulataneously, both might see the instance be null and thus both might call `m_instance = new Map_en_US();`

Since the static initializer block is executed only once (by one thread that is executing the class loader), you don't have a problem there.

[Here's a good overview.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html)

Comment: @Bruno AFAIK there's no per thread copy (unless you use `ThreadLocal`), thus after the variable is initialized, each call should return the same instance, shouldn't it? Thus assuming two thread call `getInstance()` _after_ initialization, in which case might different instances be returned (by invoking it on the same class instance, so no classloading issues here)?

Comment: no. Each thread has a local *working copy* of each variable (`ThreadLocal` or not). Sometime they get synchronized to the main memory (`ThreadLocal` works as if it didn't synchronize to the main memory). You can force the synchronization using `synchronized` or `volatile`. Without synchronization, the JVM is free to flush the contents of the local working copy of the variable to the main memory at will (the behavior is implementation dependent). So, two different threads calling getInstance() might never be able to see the instance created by the other!

Comment: @Bruno that makes sense, thanks for the explanation. I now also better understand your concerns about double checked locking. Would give you another +1 if I could :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach for eradicating the static block:

```
private static Map_en_US s_instance = new Map_en_US() {{init();}};
```

It does the same thing, but is way neater.

Explanation of this syntax:
The outer set of braces creates an anonymous class.
The inner set of braces is called an "instance block" - it fires during construction.
This syntax is often incorrectly called the "double brace initializer" syntax, usually by those who don't understand what is going on.

Also, note:
`m_` is a naming convention prefix for *instance* (ie member) fields.
`s_` is a naming convention prefix for *class* (ie static) fields.
So I changed the name of the field to `s_...`.

Comment: That wouldn't work for final classes, however. Basically the double brace syntax creates an anonymous subclass, which wouldn't compile in case `Map_en_US` was final.

Comment: @Bohemian: rigorously, it doesn't do the same thing. As you said, it creates an anonymous class that inherits from `Map_en_US`. Therefore `Map_en_US` cannot be marked `final` for this code to work.

Comment: Big deal. So, if you get a final class (not common) don't use it.

Comment: why not just call `init` in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how resource-intensive the init method is. If it e.g. does a lot of work, maybe you want that work done at the startup of the application instead of on the first call. Maybe it downloads the map from Internet? I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

The static block is executed when the class is first loaded by the JVM. As Bruno said, that helps with thread safety because there isn't a possibility that two threads will fight over the same getInstance() call for the first time.

Comment: Just remember that the static block can be executed *more than once*, if the class is loaded and initialized again by a different ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

1. With static instantiation there will be only one copy of the instance per class irrespective of how many objects being created.
2. Second advantage with the way is, The method is `thread-safe`as you are not doing anything in the method except returning the instance.

Comment: There *might* be more than one instance if the class is loaded and initialized multiple times by different class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

the static block instances your class and call the default contructor (if any) only one time and when the application starts and all static elements are loaded by the JVM.

Using the getInstance() method the object for the class is builded and initialized when the method is called and not on the static initialization. And is not really safe if you are running the getInstance() in diferent threads at the same time.

Comment: The static block isn't called at application startup. It's called only when the class is loaded and initialized, which might never happen!

Answer (score 0):

static block is here to allow for `init` invocation. Other way to code it could be eg like this (which to prefer is a matter of taste)

```
public class Map_en_US extends mapTree {

    private static
            /* thread safe without final,
               see VM spec 2nd ed 2.17.15 */
            Map_en_US m_instance = createAndInit();

    private Map_en_US() {}

    public static Map_en_US getInstance(){
        return m_instance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        //some code;
    }

    private static Map_en_US createAndInit() {
        final Map_en_US tmp = new Map_en_US();
        tmp.init();
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

---

**update** corrected per [VM spec 2.17.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#24237), details in comments

Comment: Agreed. the static block is also invoking the init(). My init() has Content that should is available when the singleton object is created

Comment: @gnat: Final is totally irrelevant here. It does not add any thread-safety. You are mixing up the semantics of `final` keyword when used in *instance* fields. The code you propose is perfectly thread-safe without `final`.

Comment: @Bruno care to provide JLS reference that would guarantee thread safety without final?

Comment: @gnat: Sure! [Section 2.17.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#24237): the lock acquisition/release on the Class object (that happens when a Thread verifies if a class is fully initialized and also when initializing the static, non-final fields -- which is the same time when the static block executes --) guarantee the visibility of the initial value of non-final, static fields due to the *happens-before* relation that exists between the release and acquisition of a given lock.

Comment: Oh, by the way, that's the VM Spec, not the JLS. But I think it's at least as authoritative as the JLS in respect to this subject.

Comment: @Bruno thanks! VM spec 2.7.15 does that guarantee I was asking about. I'll correct the code in my example

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Best way to implement the singleton class in java
    package com.vsspl.test1;

    class STest {

        private static STest ob= null;
        private  STest(){
            System.out.println("private constructor");
        }

        public static STest  create(){

            if(ob==null)
                ob = new STest();
            return ob;
        }

        public  Object  clone(){
            STest   obb = create();
            return obb;
        }
    }

    public class SingletonTest {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            STest  ob1 = STest.create();
            STest  ob2 = STest.create();
            STest  ob3 = STest.create();

            System.out.println("obj1  " +  ob1.hashCode());
            System.out.println("obj2  " +  ob2.hashCode());
            System.out.println("obj3  " +  ob3.hashCode());


            STest  ob4 = (STest) ob3.clone();
            STest  ob5 = (STest) ob2.clone();
            System.out.println("obj4  " +  ob4.hashCode());
            System.out.println("obj5  " +  ob5.hashCode());

        }
    }

-------------------------------- OUT PUT -------------------------------------
private constructor
obj1  1169863946
obj2  1169863946
obj3  1169863946
obj4  1169863946
obj5  1169863946
```

Answer (score -1):

Interesting never seen that before.  Seems largely a style preference. I suppose one difference is: the static initialisation takes place at VM startup, rather than on first request for an instance, potentially eliminating an issue with concurrent instantiations? (Which can also be handled with `synchronized getInstance()` method declaration)

Comment: Wrong. The static initialization doesn't happen at VM startup. It happens only when the class is referenced (which might never happen).

Comment: @bruno Then when is the static initialization happen? if it don't happen at the start up of the JVM. What do you mean by "it happens only when class referenced and you said that situation never happens"

Comment: @FirstHearty: it happens when when a thread of execution first encounters a reference to the class. Let's say you have a `main(...) { System.out.println("bye"); }`, it doesn't use the class `Singleton`. So there's no need for the JVM to load the class `Singleton`. Therefore it won't be initialized.