# RealTimeExample needed on static field without final keyword

Tags: java

Could you please explain me any real time scenario (or) JAVA API examples for static field without final keyword ?

I have seen in Runtime.java; to make singleton They have declared like below

private static Runtime currentRuntime = new Runtime();

But here also we need final right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter of all instances of certain type:

```
class MyClass {
    private static int count = 0;
    public MyClass() {
        count++;
    }
    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Other example is classic singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> But here also we need final right ?

Wrong.

Static initialization is thread-safe without final, see [VM spec 2.17.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#24237).

Idea that `final` is necessary in case like this is wrong, I have broken my nose on that in [one of my recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121213/singleton-instantiation/7121406#7121406).

In cases like with [Runtime.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Runtime.java.html), `final` might be useful only to help avoiding reassigning the field by mistake - assuming it is not intended to reassign.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases where `final` is not needed. For example:

```
public class Receipt {
    private static long nextId = 0;

    public static long getNextId() {
        return ++nextId;
    }

    . . .
}
```