# Static instance variable references instance of the class

Tags: java, reference

Can I let a static field of a class keep a reference to an instance of itself? If so, will it keep alive in the jvm without anyone else keeping a reference?

```
public class StatTest {
    private static StatTest statTest;

    public static StatTest getStatTest () {
        if (statTest== null) {
            statTest= new StatTest ();
            statTest.init();
        }
        return statTest;
    }

    private StatTest() { }
}
```

Comment: This is one way to implement the *singleton* pattern. Just note that this is not thread-safe (ie, things might get broken if you call `StatTest.getStatTest()` from more than one thread). To compare different singleton implementations (including some thread-safe ones), check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121213/singleton-instantiation/7121246#7121246, an answer I wrote some time ago.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! I realize now that this is a really well known pattern. I recognize the name singleton from before, but I've never read about it. Now it will be easy to find information on how to proceed. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, This is the concept of the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern!

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to create a singleton of a class.

So to answer your question:

- Yes, it is possible
- All references to the `getStatTest()` method will return that instance.

When using this method for a singleton, the method is mostly called `getInstance()` =)

Answer (score 1):

> will it keep alive in the jvm without anyone else keeping a reference?

Yes, as long as the class itself is not eligible for garbage collection (which can only happen if you use a custom classloader).

Answer (score 0):

Congrats. You've reinvented the singleton. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern