# Is code that enters a synchronized block only if the thread has actually been suspended an example of double-checked locking?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If I recall correctly there is a Sin in Java threading known as double-checked locking.

It's been a while but its something like checking a value, then if it is `true`, going into a `synchronized` block and checking it again. Since it's been such a while I can't remember why it exact flaw. I remember it being related to the Java spec allowing implementations to reorder the execution of various statements in someway (and because most didn't it normally worked).
(It's advantage was minimizing having to go into `synchronized` blocks which is slow.)

I was looking over: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
and came across:

> A simple trick can be used to remove the synchronization that we've
>   added to each iteration of the "run loop." The synchronized block that
>   was added is replaced by a slightly more complex piece of code that
>   enters a synchronized block only if the thread has actually been
>   suspended:
>
> ```
>         if (threadSuspended) {
>             synchronized(this) {
>                 while (threadSuspended)
>                     wait();
>             }
>         }
> ```

Which feels a bit like double-checked locking, but I feel imp prob wrong since it's from official documentation.

Also the fact that it is a `while` loop seems a bit off.
So is that code evil? Or not?

Comment: Should this be in Stackoverflow instead?

Comment: I've now flagged it to be moved

Comment: See http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html for an introduction.

Comment: Check an answer I wrote to a question about singleton initialization, in which I talk about the DCL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121213/singleton-instantiation/7121246#7121246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the double-checked locking pattern as no writes to shared variables are being done while the lock is held.

The main issue you might encounter is that changes of `threadSuspended` from `false` to `true` may not be noticed in quite as timely a fashion because of cache coherency or register caching issues. The register caching issues are the biggest problem (cache coherency eventually solves itself, though it may take a few microseconds), and depend greatly on the surrounding code and what the optimizer does.

If this is isolated code inside a function, it's not likely you'll have a register caching issue. If threadSuspended has been declared `volatile` you will also not have an issue as the optimizer will not register cache `volatile` things.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `volatile` keyword on the `threadSuspended` variable will give you the effect you need.  The issue is that when multiple threads are accessing the same variable, there can be thread-local caching of the variable.  The `volatile` keyword ensures that this caching does not occur.

[Here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html) is a post explaining further.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the while, since the purpose of the code is to wait until the thread is no longer suspended, I see no reason not to use a `while`.

Also, as mentioned in the comment, the line below the snippet you pasted mentions `volatile`, and the full code snippet a few lines beneath that declares `threadSuspended` as a `volatile boolean`.

Comment: yes, and the link in the OP specifically mentions this as well in the "full" code example right after the snippet included,

Answer (score 0):

Two references about double-checked locking:

- Java Concurrency in Practice, 16.2.4. Double-checked Locking
- Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `while` -- `wait()` is allowed to return spuriously -- that is, without anybody having called `notify()` on the object. This means that when `wait()` returns, it's probably, but not definitely, because someone set `threadSuspended` and then called `notify()`. The way you guard against this is by re-checking `threadSuspended`, which is what the `while` is there for.