# Can this concurrent code be simplified in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following use case: my Android application makes multiple concurrent HTTP requests to the server. If a request produces "Incorrect token" error then the application should regenerate the token by making a special request to the server and repeat the failed request.

As there are multiple concurrent requests that produce the same error and token should be generated only once I used the following construct:

```
static final AtomicBoolean isTokenSync = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private static CountDownLatch countDownLatchTokenSync;

if (isTokenSync.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        countDownLatchTokenSync = new CountDownLatch(1);

        generateAndSaveToken(...);

        isTokenSync.set(false);   
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
    else {
        try {
            countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

// repeat the request
```

Basically first thread gets through and generates the token and other threads wait until token generated and proceed. Is my code a good approach to achieve the behavior? Can it be simplified?

Comment: Your code is not thread safe because you reallocate the latch everytime - a thread could wait on the previous latch and succeed immediately. Have you considered using a simple `synchronized` block (considering you are dealing with HTTP requests, the nanoseconds of performance cost of using `synchronized` won't make a difference)?

Comment: The first thread should do the work and all successive threads should wait untill the work is done. How can this be achived by using synchronized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) here nicely.  It's like a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) that supports a dynamic number of waiting parties for all threads arriving at a phase.

```
static final AtomicBoolean isTokenSync = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private static final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

int phase = phaser.getPhase();
if (isTokenSync.compareAndSet(false, true)) {  

        generateAndSaveToken(...);

        phaser.arrive();
        isTokenSync.set(false);   
    }
    else {
        try {
            phaser.awaitAdvance(phase);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Each time you `arrive` you will increment the phase count.  So let's say your start the method at `phase == 1` the arrive will increment phase to 2 and all phases less than the current phase will advance.

Comment: thank you, this is essentially that I'd like to see. this solution seems much more thread-safe as it avoids creating new CountDownLatch object every cycle

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a `Singleton`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121246/823393) for a good answer.

Something like this should work.

```
public static class SingletonToken {

    private final String theToken;

    private SingletonToken() {
        // Do your generateAndSaveToken(...) here.
        theToken = "My token";
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {

        // The constructor is in a static so will be called only once.
        private static final SingletonToken instance = new SingletonToken();
    }

    public static String getToken() {
        // By the time the code gets here the instance has been created.
        return SingletonHolder.instance.theToken;
    }
}
```

This essentially deferrs synchronisation to the class loader which is - [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) - thread safe.

Comment: The problem is that the token can expire and the server will respond with "Incorrect token" error. To generate new token a special GET request should be made (it is as it is. this is not my design decision). And to provide a good user experience all failed requests should be immediately repeated after token generation.

Comment: @bvk256 - Are you using Java 8? If so a `ConcurrentMap` has a [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method. This will allow a "incorrect token" error to remove it from the map.

Comment: thanks, this is a valid solution, but Android supports Java only up to 7